# Mixing 2 image and increase size of new generation image

Tags: c#

I make an application that it get an image from net and mix it with an image in My Hard and generate new image. My Problem is increasing new photo size after this process.for example if main photo is 50X50 pixel with 50kb after this Operations new image is same 50X50 pixel but it new size is 400kb!

Please help me to resolve this awful problem.
I used THIS method to mix this image:

```
HttpWebRequest MakeRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ImageURL);
HttpWebResponse Respnse = (HttpWebResponse)MakeRequest.GetResponse();
Stream Streaming = Respnse.GetResponseStream();
Image ImageNews = Image.FromStream(Streaming);

imgToResize = ImageNews;


Image Logo = Image.FromFile("d:\\logonews.jpg");

Bitmap NewsMainImage = new Bitmap(ImageNews.Width, ImageNews.Height);
Graphics makeImage = Graphics.FromImage(NewsMainImage);
makeImage.DrawImage(ImageNews, 
                     new Rectangle(new Point(), ImageNews.Size), 
                     new Rectangle(new Point(), ImageNews.Size),  
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


makeImage.DrawImage(Logo, 
                    new Rectangle(new Point(0, ImageNews.Height - Logo.Height),  
                                  Logo.Size),  
                    new Rectangle(new Point(), 
                                  Logo.Size),  
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render "makeImage" as a Jpeg. You are probably returning it as a Bitmap, which causes your problem with the filesize. Rendering it as a Jpeg or Png will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

check in your makeImage variable the attribute PixelOffsetMode because is possible that is in HighQuality;

add this line:

makeImage.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;

HighSpeed sets the low Quality